# Spring security ant matcher's permitall doesn't work

Tags: spring, spring-security

As the title says Spring security's ant matcher's permit all doesn't work at all here's the method for it

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers( "/css/*", "/js/*", "index").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v1/user/auth/register").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/get", "/delete/*", "/api/v1/user/auth/**").hasRole(ADMIN.name())
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
}
```

it should only allow the url ending with /get to be accessed by user that has admin role but I can access it without it (USER role) is there anything I'm doing wrong?

I tried changing the endpoint but didn't succeed at all

Comment: `/get` doesn't mean any request ending with `/get`. It means `/get` from the root of the application.

Comment: Sorry I'm just learning spring security so what should be in its place? as the url is "api/v1/user/get"

Comment: Well if that is the URL that is what should be there.